# Rastertek DirectX11 Tutorials on Windows 10

Tags: c++, directx

I have been trying to work my way through [Rastertek's DX11 Tutorials](http://www.rastertek.com/tutdx11.html) on my Windows 10 system, and have had a lot of trouble trying to get them to work. Most of the issues I have been having are ".exe was not found" when trying to run the solutions they provide, or errors with the d3dx11 library. Does anyone have experience getting these totorials working, or have any pointers on how to get them to work on my Windows 10 system?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Those tutorials are a quite dated with the use of the legacy DirectX SDK content like `D3DX11`. You can get these to work with some effort per the instructions on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-).

The legacy DirectX SDK doesn't install the Direct3D debug device on Windows 10. You enable it as a Windows optional feature instead. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-2015-and-graphics-tools-for-windows-10/).

Many books on Direct3D 11 are still relevant, but the details around the legacy DirectX SDK are all out of date. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/book-recommendations/) for some notes.

> I'd recommend taking a looking at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/wiki/Getting-Started).